Malloc failure when working with dynamic allocation pointer to pointer
I've been working on dynamic allocation to create matrixes. The goal is to apply to computational physics. While trying to solve partial differential equation I've come across an error I never encountered before

Fatal glibc error: malloc.c:2599 (sysmalloc): assertion failed: (old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)
Aborted (core dumped)

I don't understand what could cause this error. With the help of VS Code debugger I was able to pin down the lines of code that cause it.
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int Nx=129, Ny=65;

    double **S = new double* [Nx];
    S[0] = new double [Nx*Ny];

    for (int i=1; i<Nx; i++) S[i]=S[i-1]+Nx;

    for (int i=0; i<Nx; i++) for (int j=0; j<Ny; j++) S[i][j]=0;

     for (int i=0; i<Nx; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<Ny; j++) {
            std::cout<<S[i][j]<<" "; 
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    } 
    
    double** phi0 = new double* [Nx];
    phi0[0] = new double [Nx*Ny];

    for (int i=1; i<Nx; i++) phi0[i]=phi0[i-1]+Nx;
}

Placing all elements of S equal to 0 is just for the minimal example, in reality it's more complex but it doesn't change the outcome.
I cannot print the matrix S nor declare a new matrix phi0. It is important that Nx and Ny remain the same.
I tried removing the nested for cycle that prints S, but it still gave out that error on the line delcaring phi0. If I removed only the code that declares phi0 I still get the error on the line that prints S.
If I change Nx to like 50 it works, 75 already gives the same error. However changing Nx and Ny would defeat the purpose since the excercise I'm trying to solve requires those specific Nx=129 and Ny=65.
I can guess it's due to memory&co problems, but since it's an excercise and those excercise remained the same in the course for various years I don't think it's something unfixable and that is possible to make it work with Nx=129. Any guesses?

So much manual memory management. That's so C++98 - not at all how you'd do it in modern C++. Read up on containers and smart pointers.

Recommendation: Avoid new.

Great, simple example. Step through it with a debugger and watch what's really happening. Stop as soon as you see the program deviate from your expectations because that'll be a bug you need to figure out.

Recommendation: Make full use of sanitizers. They will give you a lot of information to work with. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/Ms6To1j5j

Recommendation: Make your life easier and don't pretend at making a 2D array. Fake it out completely with a 1D array and perform your own indexing or by taking advantage of the fact that you can easily return a pointer to anywhere in the 1D array.

Even if you decide to continue on this route, encapsulate your matrix logic in a class, or a few functions if you really want to go low-brow, so that it's harder to get it right one time and not another.

double **S = new double* [Nx]; S[0] = new double [Nx*Ny];   for (int i=1; i<Nx; i++) S[i]=S[i-1]+ Nx ; Should be Ny Easy mistake to make. In addition to other comments, this approach is not exception safe.

In my real world C++ project, I have not needed to use new directly in any code for 13 years now.  We have std::vector, which is a smart container to manage the memory details for you.  Combine that with mapping a 2D matrix to a 1D vector, and you've elminated a ton of headaches for yourself.  (Wrap the 1D vector inside your own Matrix class.  operator()(size_t x, size_t y) for a convenient accessor, albeit with nailclipping parens instead of square brackets.)

See also matrix FAQ

S[0] is a (dynamically allocated) array of Nx * Ny elements (which for discussion purposes I'll call A). The first loop assigns S[1] equal to &A[Nx], S[2] to &A[2*Nx], S[Nx] to &A[(Nx-1)*Nx]. Ny is less than Nx, so some of those pointers point past the end of A.  The next (two nested) loops then assign non-existent elements of A to zero so cause undefined behaviour.  Anything can happen then - including (presumably) in your case, overwriting data structures used internally by malloc(), which triggers an assertion failure in one of the subsequent new expressions.

I've been working on dynamic allocation to create matrixes. --  The goal is to apply to computational physics. -- If your goal was to build a table, do you build the hammer, screwdrivers, etc?  No, you buy (or get) those basic items and use them to build the table.  Same thing with your program -- use what already exists, i.e. std::vector, and then you can spend the time to reach your actual goal.  See this example.  That class is simple, has no memory leaks, creates a contiguous array of data that can be accessed using [][], etc.
